# Подключение пакетов CMAKE с использованием FIND_PACKAGE

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, clion

Возможно тема вопроса старая, и множество ответов на нее есть.
В общем, при компилировании проектов с `github` при попытке установки все происходит успешно, файл поиска библиотеки копируется в папку

```
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/cmake/Modules/FindSDL2PP.cmake
```

Но, при попытке подключения пакета через `FIND_PACKAGE`, `cmake` всегда говорит что не может найти файл поиска библиотеки, при том что если пакеты устанавливать из терминала, ту же библиотеку `libvlc-dev`, `libvlccore-dev` или любую другую, cmake никогда не найдет пакеты через `FIND_PACKAGE`.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/SDL2/)
set(SDL2_LIBRARY /usr/lib/)

find_file(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR NAME SDL.h HINTS SDL2)
find_library(SDL2_LIBRARY NAME SDL2)

FIND_PACKAGE(SDL2PP REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SDL2PP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2PP_LIBRARIES})
```

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindSDL2PP.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2PP", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2PP" with any
  of the following names:

    SDL2PPConfig.cmake
    sdl2pp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SDL2PP" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SDL2PP_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SDL2PP"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

В чем может быть проблема с поиском библиотек? Уже устал вручную прописывать пути к библиотекам и их заголовочным файлам.

Для поиска `SDL2` использую полукостыль такого вида:

```
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/SDL2/)
set(SDL2_LIBRARY /usr/lib/)

find_file(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR NAME SDL.h HINTS SDL2)
find_library(SDL2_LIBRARY NAME SDL2)
```

Вот один из проектов/враппер над `SDL2`: [libSDL2pp](https://github.com/libSDL2pp/libSDL2pp)

Вывод `make && make install`:

```
[ 19%] Built target SDL2pp
[ 21%] Built target ttf
[ 22%] Built target mixer_effects
[ 24%] Built target mixer_music
[ 26%] Built target mixer_music_sine
[ 27%] Built target rendertarget
[ 29%] Built target sprites
[ 31%] Built target audio_wav
[ 32%] Built target audio_sine
[ 34%] Built target image
[ 35%] Built target fill
[ 37%] Built target lines
[ 39%] Built target mixer
[ 41%] Built target live_mixer
[ 43%] Built target live_window
[ 44%] Built target live_rendering
[ 45%] Built target live_audiodevice
[ 46%] Built target test_surface
[ 48%] Built target test_optional
[ 49%] Built target SDL2pp_SDLMixer_hh_test
[ 51%] Built target SDL2pp_Optional_hh_test
[ 52%] Built target SDL2pp_Texture_hh_test
[ 53%] Built target SDL2pp_AudioDevice_hh_test
[ 55%] Built target test_error
[ 57%] Built target SDL2pp_Exception_hh_test
[ 59%] Built target test_color_constexpr
[ 60%] Built target SDL2pp_RWops_hh_test
[ 62%] Built target SDL2pp_ContainerRWops_hh_test
[ 64%] Built target test_wav
[ 66%] Built target SDL2pp_Rect_hh_test
[ 68%] Built target SDL2pp_Window_hh_test
[ 70%] Built target SDL2pp_SDLTTF_hh_test
[ 71%] Built target SDL2pp_Renderer_hh_test
[ 72%] Built target test_font
[ 74%] Built target test_rwops
[ 75%] Built target SDL2pp_Music_hh_test
[ 76%] Built target SDL2pp_Color_hh_test
[ 78%] Built target SDL2pp_SDL_hh_test
[ 80%] Built target SDL2pp_SDL2pp_hh_test
[ 82%] Built target SDL2pp_Surface_hh_test
[ 84%] Built target SDL2pp_Wav_hh_test
[ 86%] Built target test_pointrect_constexpr
[ 88%] Built target SDL2pp_AudioSpec_hh_test
[ 89%] Built target SDL2pp_StreamRWops_hh_test
[ 91%] Built target SDL2pp_Point_hh_test
[ 93%] Built target SDL2pp_Mixer_hh_test
[ 94%] Built target SDL2pp_Font_hh_test
[ 95%] Built target test_pointrect
[ 97%] Built target SDL2pp_SDLImage_hh_test
[ 98%] Built target test_color
[100%] Built target SDL2pp_Chunk_hh_test
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/AudioDevice.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/AudioSpec.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Color.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/ContainerRWops.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Exception.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Optional.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Point.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/RWops.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Rect.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Renderer.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/SDL.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/SDL2pp.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/StreamRWops.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Surface.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Texture.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Wav.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Window.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/SDLTTF.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Font.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/SDLImage.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Chunk.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Mixer.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Music.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/SDLMixer.hh
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Config.hh
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/Export.hh
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/SDL2pp/external/libcpp_optional.hh
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libSDL2pp.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sdl2pp.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/cmake/Modules/FindSDL2PP.cmake
```

Comment: А где собственно попытка использования find package?

Comment: Добавил cmakelists

Comment: Думаю лучше будет вам вручную написать FindSDL2PP.cmake и указать там верные пути

Comment: А почему Вы считаете, что CMake должен искать файл модулей по этому пути? Во что установлен `CMAKE_ROOT`?

Comment: @ixSci: Вы правы, `CMAKE_ROOT` имеет другой путь `/snap/clion/27/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.10`.

Answer (score 1):

Тут видимо проблема в неправильном режиме использования макроса `find_package`. По-умолчанию он работает в режиме `Module` и игнорирует модули установленные через install. Соответственно тут имеет смысл использовать его в режиме `Config` использовав одноименную волшебную директиву:

```
find_package(SDL2PP CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Такой способ тоже не работает. Ошибка `cmake` ровно такая же как и без `CONFIG`.

Answer (score 1):

В никсах cmake ищет заголовки и библиотеки с помощью pkgcong, который, собственно, и рапортует о провале поиска. В случае, если Вы видите в выдаче cmake

```
-- Checking for module 'бла-бла'
--   Package 'бла-бла', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

то определенно помогает установка переменной среды PKG_CONFIG_PATH, где располагаются .pk файлы ваших пакетов. Например, при сборке edb cmake не находит пакета gdtoa-desktop, если тот установлен в /usr/local. Если же сказать

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig cmake ..
```

то cmake отрабатывает без ошибок и пердуперждений.

Answer (score 1):

> файл поиска библиотеки копируется в папку
>
> `-- Installing: /usr/local/share/cmake/Modules/FindSDL2PP.cmake`

Сразу две ошибки:

1. Никогда не устанавливайте модуль в папку `Modules` самого CMake.
   Эта директория только для родных модулей CMake.
2. При установке библиотеки XXX должен устанавливаться не файл `FindXXX.cmake`, подходящий для MODULE режима [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html), а файл `XXXConfig.cmake` (или `xxx-config.cmake`), подходящий для CONFIG режима.

Разница между скриптами "Find" и "Config" в том, что:

1. "Find" скрипт **ищет** библиотеку, так как не знает, где она **установлена**.
   Не знает потому, что этот скрипт поставляется **отдельно** от библиотеки.
2. "Config" скрипт ничего **не ищет**: он точно знает, где библиотека установлена.
   А всё потому, что этот скрипт собирается и устанавливается **вместе** с библиотекой.

CMake предоставляет команду `install(EXPORT)`, которая сама создаёт "Config" скрипт для устанавливаемых таргетов (target). Более подробно про эти скрипты можно почитать в [документации](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html).